# How to refactor a drag-and-drop file Chrome extension to resolve CORB errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have an old Chrome extension that added drag-and-drop functionality to a site with file uploads. The site has pages on one subdomain (ex: https://foo.site.com/page1.php, https://foo.site.com/page2.php..), and the upload endpoint is on another subdomain (ex: https://bar.site.com/upload.php). Starting in some previous Chrome version, the extension stopped working because of stricter CORS rules. The POST to upload the file seems to succeed, but the response is blocked with a CORB error, and I need the response to know where the file's new remote path is.

I've attempted to refactor by moving requests from the content script to the background script, per Google's guidelines. However, I can't figure out how to share a file drag-and-dropped onto the page with the background script. Here's some sample code:

content.js:

```
var setupDragAndDrop = function () {
  (
    document.getElementById("some_element")
  ).addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
    for (var t = 0, s = e.dataTransfer.files.length; t < s; t++)
      upload(e.dataTransfer.files[t], function (e) {
        insertResponseOnPage(e); // Use the upload response to show the new remote path on the page
      });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
},

var upload = function(file, callback) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      need: "upload",
      file: file,
      callback: callback
    }
  );
}
```

background.js (there is some other logic that lets the message end up at this method, but it does end up here with the file and callback):

```
var upload = function(file, callback) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  const UPLOAD_URL = 'https://bar.site.com/upload.php';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', UPLOAD_URL, true);
  xhr.withCredentials = "true";

  xhr.onload = callback;

  xhr.send(formData);
};
```

This issue I'm seeing is that the `file` ending up on the background page is an empty object. I believe I read somewhere that whatever is sent with the message API needs to be JSON serializable, so I'm assuming `File` is not? I get the same behavior if I attempt to send a `FormData` object as well. I've also tried going down the route of somehow getting the file path instead and recreating the file in the background page, but apparently you can't get the path from a system file in JS for security reasons.

Is there any way to fix up this extension? I do not own the site this extension attempts to add functionality to, so I can't move the upload endpoint onto the same subdomain.

Comment: JSON comprises string, number, boolean, null, and arrays/object of these types. You'll have to read the file contents in the content script as a string and send it to the background script where you will either reconstruct the file object or forge the `body` manually as multipart/form-data. Note, maximum message size is 64MB in UTF-8 encoding so if the file is bigger you'll have to send it in chunks via multiple messages. Another possibility is to convert the file to a blob URL via URL.createObjectURL and use it in the background script.

Comment: There's a better solution: display the file uploader in an iframe that points to an extension html file exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) - the scripts inside will run in the extension context and will be able to use cross-origin XHR directly without the need to send to the background script.